# Language theoretic comparison of LL and LR grammars

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, parsers, reference-question

People often say that [LR(k)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) parsers are more powerful than [LL(k)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) parsers. These statements are vague most of the time; in particular, should we compare the classes for a fixed $k$ or the union over all $k$? So how is the situation really? In particular, I am interested in how LL(*) fits in.

As far as I know, the respective sets of grammars LL and LR parsers accept are orthogonal, so let us talk about the languages generated by the respective sets of grammars. Let $LR(k)$ denote the class of languages generated by grammars that can be parsed by an $LR(k)$ parser, and similar for other classes.

I am interested in the following relations:

- $LL(k) \overset{?}{\subseteq} LR(k)$
- $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} LL(k) \overset{?}{\subseteq} \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} LR(k)$
- $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} LL(k) \overset{?}{=} LL(*)$
- $LL(*) \overset{?}{\circ} \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} LR(k)$

Some of these are probably easy; my goal is to collect a "complete" comparison. References are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can help you! [Grammar Hierarchy image](http://underpop.free.fr/j/java/modern-compiler-implementation-in-java/images/fig3-29_0.jpg)

Comment: @AndreaTucci: Yes, but that only covers the grammars, not the generated languages.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are numerous containments known. Let $\subseteq$ denote containment and $\subset$ proper containment. Let $\times$ denote incomparability.

Let $LL = \bigcup_k LL(k)$, $LR = \bigcup_k LR(k)$.

### Grammar level

#### For LL

- $LL(0) \subset LL(1) \subset LL(2) \subset LL(2) \subset \cdots \subset LL(k) \subset \cdots \subset LL \subset LL(*)$
- $SLL(1) = LL(1), SLL(k) \subset LL(k), SLL(k+1) \times LL(k)$

Most of these are proven in [Properties of deterministic top down grammars](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=805431) by Rosenkrantz and Stearns. $SLL(k+1) \times LL(k)$ is a rather trivial exercise. [This presentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20121114144945/http://www.antlr.org/workshop/ANTLR2005/presentations/LL-Star.ppt) by Terence Parr places $LL(*)$ on slide 13. The paper LL-regular grammars by Jarzabek and Krawczyk show $LL \subset LLR$, and their proof trivially extends to $LL \subset LL(*)$

#### For LR

- $LR(0) \subset SLR(1) \subset LALR(1) \subset LR(1)$
- $SLR(k) \subset LALR(k) \subset LR(k)$
- $SLR(1) \subset SLR(2) \subset \cdots \subset SLR(k)$
- $LALR(1) \subset LALR(2) \subset \cdots \subset LALR(k)$
- $LR(0) \subset LR(1) \subset LR(2) \subset \cdots \subset LR(k) \subset \cdots \subset LR$

These are all simple exercises.

#### LL versus LR

- $LL(k) \subset LR(k)$ ([Properties of deterministic top down grammars](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=805431) plus any left recursive grammar)
- $LL(k) \times SLR(k), LALR(k), LR(k-1)$ (simple exercise)
- $LL \subset LR$ (any left recursive grammar)
- $LL(*) \times LR$ (left recursion versus arbitrary lookahead)

### Language level

#### For LL

- $LL(0) \subset LL(1) \subset LL(2) \subset \cdots \subset LL(k) \subset \cdots \subset LL \subset LL(*)$
- $SLL(k) = LL(k)$

Most of these are proven in [Properties of deterministic top down grammars](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=805431). [The equivalence problem for LL- and LR-regular grammars](http://doc.utwente.nl/66932/1/fct1981.pdf) by Nijholt makes references to papers showing $LL(k) \subset LL(*)$. The paper LL-regular grammars by Jarzabek and Krawczyk show $LL \subset LLR$, and their proof trivially extends to $LL \subset LL(*)$

#### For LR

- $LR(0) \subset SLR(1) = LALR(1) = LR(1) = SLR(k) = LALR(k) = LR(k) = LR$

Some of these were proven by Knuth in his paper [On the Translation of Languages from Left to Right](http://www.dc.uba.ar/materias/tl/2010/c2/files/Knuth-1965-TranslationofLanguages.pdf) in which he introduced LR(k), the rest are proven in [Transforming LR(k) Grammars to LR(1), SLR(1), and (1,1) Bounded Right-Context Grammars](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321972) by Mickunas et al.

#### LL versus LR

- $LL \subset LR(1)$ (containment follows from the above, $\{ a^i b^j | i \geq j \}$ is the canonical example for strict containment)
- $LL(*) \times LR$ (the language $\{ a^i b^j | i \geq j \}$ shows half the claim, and the introduction of [The equivalence problem for LL- and LR-regular grammars](http://doc.utwente.nl/66932/1/fct1981.pdf) by Nijholt makes references to papers showing the other half)
- $LR(1) = DCFL$ (see e.g. reference [here](http://planetmath.org/lrk#Thmthm1)).

Comment: Excellent answer though, I had already upvoted. I would have thought Frank deRemer proved LALR <= LR in his original LALR paper? (1969?)

Comment: @EJP: $LALR(k) \subseteq LR(k)$ is immediate if you define $LALR$ by collapsing $LR$ states. deRemer only proved that his construction created the same parser. The grammar classes are not equal, which is a nice exercise (or even a nice question for this site). The language class equality is a lot more tricky: read the paper if you really want the details ;)

Comment: @AlextenBrink I did read the paper, and was taught by Frank de Remer, but it's 30+ years ago ;-) Thanks for all the detail.

Comment: It might be nice to collect example grammars for each inequality.

Comment: @o11c I think that would overburden a single answer. My impression is that Alex gave good references where necessary; he states "easy exercise" for some. I guess if a reader can not come up with a grammar, they can post a new question asking for that specific case.

Comment: Surprised at how languages have equality when grammars have containment. For grammars, we have $LR(0)\subset SLR(1)\subset LALR(1)\subset LR(1)$. For languages, we have $LR(0)\subset SLR(1) = LALR(1)=LR(1)$. Why is this so?

Comment: What does it mean "$SLL(k+1) \times LL(k)$ is a rather trivial exercise."?  Which statement is trivial?  What does "$\times$" mean here?  If it is the Cartesian product operation, or any other operation, the sentence does not make sense.

Comment: @alexey: $\times$ in this answer means "no containment relationship". In other words, $A\times B$ means that  both $A-B$ and $B-A$ are non-empty.

Comment: @rici, where does this use of "times" symbol come from? This is not what it normally means. In fact, i've never heard of using "times" for a relation instead of an operation...

Comment: @alexey: it should be a big X. (As in Not, or crossed-out). There is probably something more X-like than the times sign, but I've seen it used that way before.

Comment: @rici, the symbol used here is times, but even for X, where does this usage come from?  I doubt this to be coming from mathematics...

Comment: @akexey I guess it comes from [X mark](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark) often used in opposition to [check mark](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark). So it has a negative connotation in common usage. There are some very clunky symbols for "incomparable"; according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols), it  is $\mid\mid$ but I wonder if that would have been obvious to a casual reader. Indeed, writing the two bars crossed feels more incomparable to me :-)

Comment: According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser), "It was also proven that there exist LR(1) languages that are not LALR." Is this a contradiction to what you wrote in the answer?