# Is the set of LL(*) grammars the same as the set of CFG grammars?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Is the set of LL(*) grammars the same as the set of context-free grammars?

Comment: @reinierpost: thank you. The reason I asked though was because extensive Google searching yielded no results. The + operator is also deprecated in favor of inferior "Verbatim" search, fyi. I shall ask future such questions at cs.stackexchange

Comment: It seems that the post linked by Alex states that unlimited lookahead with LL(*) does not magically allow for left-recursion, which was the heart of my question.

Comment: An example of a rather nasty non-LL(*) grammar is EPAL: $S \rightarrow a S a | b S b | aa | bb$. I've tried this myself and ANTLR v3.0 doesn't accept this grammar. Maybe @TerenceParr can shed some light on whether ANTLR v4.0 does parse this grammar correctly?

Comment: related: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43/language-theoretic-comparison-of-ll-and-lr-grammars/48#48

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, since no `LL(*)` grammar can be left-recursive and obviously there are context-free grammars which are left-recursive.

As requested: A sample of a left-recursive, context-free grammar (which is therefore not `LL(*)`) :

```
S -> S x
   | ɛ
```

The language this grammar describes is *one or more times the character 'x'*.

Comment: An example would improve this answer greatly.

Answer (score 7):

Static LL(*) grammar analysis is undecidable. In other words, there are some grammars that are LL(*) but we can't figure this out statically. ANTLR v3 fails over to backtracking in this case and therefore can exhibit the PEG A->a/ab problem where ab is dead code in the cases where grammar analysis failed.

In ANTLR v4, I'm introducing adaptive LL(*), which does all grammar analysis at runtime. Because I have an actual input stream in my paw, I can discover every LL(*) decision. I'm also including full LL context (vs Strong LL == SLL context which is weaker). Because I also rewrite all immediate left recursion on-the-fly, ANTLR v4 handles all CFG except for indirect left recursive ones. These are much less common than the immediate left recursive ones like expressions.

```
e : e '*' e
  | e '+' e
  | INT
  ;
```

This works fine in v4.  operator precedence is assumed to go from highest to lowest for ambiguous alternatives.