# Are LR(k) languages and DCFLs equivalent?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, lr-k

In the familiar book of *Theory of Computation* by *M. Sipser*, the author proved that for *endmarked* context-free languages, the set of languages having a LR(k) grammar for a predefined $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (denoted as LR(k) languages) *is* the set of deterministic context-free languages (denoted as DCFL).

My question is also about the relation of those two sets, but in the broader field of all context-free languages. Specifically, *are LR(k) languages and DCFLs equivalent?* And, in which book can I find a proof?

For now, I just have some surrounding facts as followed. Also in the book, the author proved that LR(0) languages *strictly* belong to DCFLs, and LR(k) languages belong to DCFLs for all $k \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$. In addition, it's obvious that LR(a) languages belong to LR(b) languages for all $0 \le a < b$. Recently, I've got an unchecked fact from [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60763/does-my-grammar-contradict-ll-%E2%8A%86-lr1): LR(1) languages and DCFLs are equivalent.

Comment: [This question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43/98) resp. its answer may be interesting for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#Theory):

- For every fixed $k \geq 1$: A language has an LR($k$) grammar iff it is DCFL.
- A language has an LR(0) grammar iff it is DCFL and has the prefix property (no word is a prefix of another word).

The first property is proved in [Knuth's original paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995865904262), in Section V on page 628.