# Can all LL(k) grammar can be recognized by LR(1)?

Tags: compilers, parsers

For context free languages, I wonder that if all LL(k) languages can be recognized by a LR(1) grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See [Language theoretic comparison of LL and LR grammars](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43/755).  In particular, https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/48/755 says $LL \subset LR(1)$, where $LL = \cup_k LL(k)$, hence $LL(k) \subseteq LL \subset LR(1)$ for all $k$.

See also [Does my grammar contradict LL ⊆ LR(1)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60763/755).  Make sure to distinguish between a grammar vs the language accepted by the grammar.

Comment: @reinierpost, No worries, and thank you for reviewing my post and the other links!  I appreciate your time to keep the quality of this site high!